# Environment variables propagation in podman

Tags: deployment, podman

I'm running a simple Kubernetes deployment descriptor with `podman play kube` and some of my services need env vars to be set. In Docker Compose/Swarm I could just place the names of env-vars to the file and they would be picked up from a host OS. Alternatively, I could use `.env` file with Docker Compose for this purpose. But none of these seem to work with podman. I know that Kubernetes offers ConfigMaps for this purpose, but it also doesn't seem to be implemented in `podman play kube`. So what's the way of propagating OS environment variables to the container in this case, because I don't really want to explicitly hardcode the values in the `.yaml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Podman 2.2.0**](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v2.2.0) (released in December 2020) mentions this in the release notes:

*The `podman play kube` command now supports Kubernetes configmaps via the `--configmap` option*

Here is a link to the latest [manual page](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/source/markdown/podman-play-kube.1.md#--configmappath).